# How to redirect / forward domain (including subdomain and routes)

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain

I have two domains: `example.com` and `example.net`. I want to redirect / forward every thing from `example.com` to `example.net`, for example:

- `mysite.com` => `example.net`
- `api.mysite.com` => `api.example.net`
- `mysite.com/news` => `example.net/news`

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache?

Comment: I'm using none of them but I think if necessary I will setup one. I'd prefer nginx

Comment: You can configure it easily on NGINX. You will just need wildcard configuration to forward all request from site.com to site.net.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy on NGINX.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.example\.com$;

    return 301 $scheme://$subdomain.example.net$request_uri;
}
```

You can use whatever redirect code you want instead of 301. You can read about redirect codes from [this post](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection).